# Is flush log happen when applying mysqldump

Tags: mysql, database-backups

Question regarding MysqlDump process .

While taking mysqldump , is flush log happen ?
Lets say if mysqldump with single-transaction running so is new binary log file will create ?

Answer (score 0):

Not by default. There's a `--flush-logs` option for mysqldump that you can use to make this happen.

Read about it here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_flush-logs